# EM algorithm python on MNIST image data

Tags: python, pixel, mnist, gmm, expectation-maximization

I need to implement the EM algorithm for fitting a GMM on image data (pixels). The data was provided as a .mat file. The data is similar to the MNIST dataset. So it's a matrix of images with the shape 784 x 1990. There are 1990 images, and each column of the matrix corresponds to one image of size  28 x 28 pixels (so 28*28 = 784).

I see alot of examples online for EM in python, but none for working with images. Most generate data like below. How should I work with these image vectors of pixels? I'm unsure how to reshape it or how to begin this task. Do I average the pixels of each column? What should my target X be- a list or a list of lists? In my humble opinion, I think I need to get x,y coordinates of each black and white image.

```
random_seed=36788765
np.random.seed(random_seed)

Mean1 = 2.0  # Input parameter, mean of first normal probability distribution
Standard_dev1 = 4.0 #@param {type:"number"}
Mean2 = 9.0 # Input parameter, mean of second normal  probability distribution
Standard_dev2 = 2.0 #@param {type:"number"}

# generate data
y1 = np.random.normal(Mean1, Standard_dev1, 1000)
y2 = np.random.normal(Mean2, Standard_dev2, 500)
data=np.append(y1,y2)
```

Or like this, where there is an X and Y to generate a scatter plot:

````
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

# Create dataset
X,Y = make_blobs(cluster_std=1.5,random_state=20,n_samples=500,centers=3)```
````

Comment: maybe this blog will help [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/group-similar-image-by-using-the-gaussian-mixture-model-em-algorithm-438e9744660c)

Comment: Is there a GitHub link to go with the blog?

Comment: It is already in the blog check it [link](https://github.com/Aksh-kumar/PYTHONMLAPI)